# Block replacement in sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a block in a file using sed, but with no success.

E.g.
I want to replace this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; ++i) {
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

With this:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < MAX_LOOPS) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Why would you prefer to use while instead of for? To me that seems to be a huge downgrade in readability and maintainability.

Comment: The difficulty here is what needs to be catered for within the while() {} loop - if it just a simple instruction that is one thing, but if it is nested blocks etc. then that is another.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick but in a very basic way, i.e. it's not robust nor does it worry with formatting.

s/for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; ++i)/int i = 0;\nwhile(i < MAX_LOOPS)/g
  /printf("Hello World!");/{
  a++i;
  }

This is just a quick hack but it ought to be enough to get you going.  Sed may not be the best tool for this job but it doesn't hurt to know how to do it in Sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '/^for.* {/,/^}/{/for/{i\int i = 0;'\
>   -e ';c\while(i < MAX_LOOPS) {'\
>   -e '}};/^}/i\++i'  file
int i = 0;
while(i < MAX_LOOPS) {
    printf("Hello World!");
++i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '
    /for\s*\(.*;.*;.*\)/!b
    s#.*\((.*);(.*);(.*)\).*#\1\nwhile (\2) {\a\3#
    h
    s/.*\a//
    x
    s/\a.*//
    :X
    N
    /}/!{bX}
    G
    s#(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)#\1\n   \3\n\2#
' file

int i = 0
while ( i < MAX_LOOPS) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    ++i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   /for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; ++i) {/,/}/ {
      /}/ a \
int i = 0;\
while(i < MAX_LOOPS) {\
    printf("Hello World!");\
    ++i;\
}
      d
      }
   '  YourFile
```

- delete all lines between *for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LOOPS; ++i) {* and *}*
- when reaching  *}* append the new content (before deleting the input line.

It use the different behaviour between input and ouptut. Append send info to output without putting this info in current working buffer (feed by input and moification) so delete cannot touch this but input (current line *}* here)is well touched